Dedekind cuts: connection to Pythagorean triples?
I'm trying to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is a Dedekind cut, and there is a proof in the book (Goldrei's Classic Set Theory), but I am trying to see if there is an alternate method. Specifically, the 3rd part of the definition of Dedekind cut, that it has no maximal element, is the main challenge. So supposing $r$ is such a cut, I must show that $\forall p \in r, \exists q <r \ni p<q.$ So let $p \in r$, thus $p^2 < 2 \wedge p \in \mathbb Q.$ Since $p \in \mathbb Q, \exists x, y \ni p=x/y$ where $x, y $ are both positive integers. (If one is negative the proof is trivial (likewise if $x=0$) and if both are negative then the fraction is still positive, so WLOG assume both are positive.)
Viewing $x/y$ as the ratio of (integer) sides of a right triangle such that when that ratio is squared it is slightly less than 2, I'm wondering how to find the "next" triangle, meaning integers $z$ and $w$ s.t. $x/y < z/w < \sqrt2$, so that $z/w$ will serve as the $q$ needed to complete the proof.
To make it even more challenging, we can stipulate that the triangle must also be a Pythagorean triple. Is that possible as well?

This is a bit unclear about how the Pythagorean triples are actually constructed. Does the following match your idea? If $a<b<c$ form a Pythagorean triple then $$c^2=a^2+b^2<b^2+b^2=2b^2$$ and so ${c\over b}<\sqrt{2}$. You're asking whether, given integers $c,b$ such that ${c\over b}<\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{c^2-b^2}\in\mathbb{Z}$, we can efficiently find integers $c',b'$ such that ${c\over b}<{c'\over b'}<\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{c'^2-b'^2}\in\mathbb{Z}$. Is that right?

If $\frac{p^2}{q^2}  < 2$  with $p,q > 0,$    we have  $p^2 - 2 q^2 = -n <0.$  Define larger  positive integers $u = 3p+4q, ; ; v = 2u + 3v ; . ; ; $ Confirm that $u^2 - 2 v^2 = -n$  but $ \frac{p}{q}  < \frac{u}{v} $

@WillJagy If $v=2u+3v$, isn't that just saying that $v=-u?$

Should have written  $v = 2p+3q.$  The matrix of the transformation is $$ P  = \left(
\begin{array}{rr}
3 & 4 \
2 & 3 \
\end{array}
\right)
$$  so that, with  $$ H  = \left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \
0 &-2 \
\end{array}
\right)
$$  we have $$P^T HP = H  $$

@WillJagy Nice linear algebra tie-in, thanks

Hank, the traditional English name for such a matrix $P$  was "automorph"  for the quadratic form $x^2 - 2 y^2.$  Given that the collection of integer $P,$  makes a group,  it is also called the symmetry group, rotation group, orthogonal group, duplicating group, some names from the German.    try some references from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_quadratic_form
